# column 'MinhaColuna' does not exist - Uso de SQLite Android

Tags: android, sqlite

Olá, estou tentando recuperar os dados gravados em meu banco de dados, porem, quando executo uma função para retornar o valor de uma das colunas criadas no banco de dados SQLite na memória do celular, apresenta o seguinte erro:

```
column 'quantidade' does not exist
```

BancoInterno:

```
private static String nomebanco = "bancoma.db";
public static String tabela = "pedidoitens";
public static String id = "_id";
public static String item = "item";
public static String quantidade = "quantidade";
public static String valorunitario = "valorunitario";
private static int versao = 1;

public BancoInterno(Context context) {
    super(context, nomebanco, null, versao, null);
}

@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
    String sql = "CREATE TABLE "+tabela+"( "
            +id+" integer primary key autoincrement, "
            +item+" text(200), "
            +quantidade+" integer(3), "
            +valorunitario+" real(3,2)"
            +")";
    db.execSQL(sql);
}

@Override
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
    db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS "+tabela);
    onCreate(db);
}
```

Banco controlador:

```
private SQLiteDatabase db;
private BancoInterno banco;

public BancoControlador(Context context){
    banco = new BancoInterno(context);
}

public String InserirDados(String item, int quantidade, double valorunitario){

    ContentValues valores;
    long resultado;

    db = banco.getWritableDatabase(); // Criar banco para inserção
    valores = new ContentValues(); // Instancia os valores

    valores.put(BancoInterno.item, item); // Inserindo..
    valores.put(BancoInterno.quantidade, quantidade);
    valores.put(BancoInterno.valorunitario, valorunitario);

    resultado = db.insert(BancoInterno.tabela, null, valores);

    if(resultado==-1)
    {
        return "Erro para gravar os dados";
    }
    else {
        return "Gravado com sucesso";
    }
}

public Cursor carregaDados(){ //Sem Where
    Cursor cursor;
    String[] campos = {banco.id,banco.item};
    db = banco.getReadableDatabase();

    cursor = db.query(banco.tabela, campos, null, null, null, null, null);

    return cursor;
}
```

Porem, como dito acima, executo essa função em minha activity, retornando o erro:

```
control = new BancoControlador(getApplicationContext());
            cursor = control.carregaDados();
            while(cursor.moveToNext())
            {
                String produto = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow("item"));
                int quantidade = cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow("quantidade"));
                //String valorunitario = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow("valorunitario"));
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), produto+"  ", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

O cursor retornado por `control.carregaDados()` apenas retorna as colunas **_id** e **item**.

Veja que na implementação

```
public Cursor carregaDados(){ //Sem Where
    Cursor cursor;
    String[] campos = {banco.id,banco.item};
    db = banco.getReadableDatabase();

    cursor = db.query(banco.tabela, campos, null, null, null, null, null);

    return cursor;
}
```

são apenas indicadas essas colunas

```
String[] campos = {banco.id,banco.item};
```

Comment: Eu olhei isso, fui corrigir outro erro e esqueci, depois quebrei cabeça atoa. Muito obrigado!